# group by day/month and take average of rating on that day/month in mongo

Tags: mongodb, date, group-by

I have this data in mongodb:

```
[
  {
    "rating": 4,
    "ceatedAt": ISODate("2016-08-08T15:32:41.262+0000")
  },
  {
    "rating": 3,
    "createdAt": ISODate("2016-08-08T15:32:41.262+0000")
  },
  {
    "rating": 3,
    "ceatedAt": ISODate("2016-07-01T15:32:41.262+0000")
  },
  {
    "rating": 5,
    "createdAt": ISODate("2016-07-01T15:32:41.262+0000")
  }
]
```

I need to take the average of rating for that particular day/month depending upon the filter criteria. 
if the filter range for date is less than a month then it will be grouped basis on day. if filter range for date is more than a month, then it will be grouped basis on month.

This is what I am kind of expecting

```
[
  {
    "average": 3.5,
    "ceatedAt": "2016-08-08",
    "month": "August"
  },
  {
    "average": 4,
    "ceatedAt": 2016-07-01,
    "month": "July"
  }
]
```

How can I do it in mongodb?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To group documents by day/month and return the month key in your output, you need to first **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** the key fields to appropriate formats using the [Date](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#date-operators) operators, in particular the **[`$dateToString`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/#exp._S_dateToString)** and **[`$month`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/month/#exp._S_month)** operators.

This can be done in a **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** stage prior to the **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** step  but not necessary since the **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline accommodates mostly the [accumulator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#accumulators) operators.

In the preceding **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline, you can the group the documents by the formatted date key, aggregate using the **[`$avg`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/#grp._S_avg)** operator and return the month as an integer from the previous pipeline using **[`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/#grp._S_first)** accumulator operator.

Running the following aggregation pipeline should give you the desired result:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": { 
        "$dateToString": { "format": "%Y-%m-%d", "date": "$ceatedAt" } 
    },
    "average": { "$avg": "$rating" },
    "month": { "$first": { "$month": "$ceatedAt" } },
  } }
])
```

Comment: If I want to add $match, how can I do it? I tried but it always gives me empty array, instead data is available for that $match query.

Comment: What will your filtering criteria be? You did not explicitly mention the filter in your question, please update your question accordingly so that I can update my answer with the `$match` filter.

Comment: Okay. I figured that out, it worked. But if I want to group by months or weeks, then how do I do it? Will I need to do another group after projection?

Comment: Looks like the original problem is solved isn't it? As for the "next" problem, that would be a **[different question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions "at Stack Exchange sites, “chameleon questions” are not quite welcome")**, consider posting it separately.

Comment: posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39269760/group-by-day-month-week-basis-on-the-date-range

Comment: Is it possible that I get formattedDate as unix timestamp?

Comment: Yes, but I'm afraid that would require posting a new question since [**chameleon questions**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) are really discouraged here on SO.

Comment: posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39274311/convert-iso-date-to-timestamp-in-mongo-query

Answer (score 1):

For the collection, use an `aggregate()` to `$group`, with the grouping `_id` of the `$month` from the `ceatedAt` (sic) field of your documents, and make the `month` field in the outputted document equal that value.

Then, create a field named `ceatedAt` that uses `$dateToString` to `format` the `$date` field of the inputted document as `"%Y-%m-%d"`.

Finally, create a field named `average`, that is the `$avg` of the `$rating` field of the inputted document, in your  grouped documents.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: { month: { $month: "$ceatedAt" } },
      date: { first: "$ceatedAt" },
      average: { $avg: "$rating" }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      month: "$month",
      ceatedAt: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$date" } },
      average: "$average"
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: I am getting an error: `unknown group operator '$dateToString'`

Comment: @phantomphoenix Type `mongo -v` in your console. You need version 3.0 or higher.

Comment: I'm running 3.4 and I get the same error as @nirvair unless I use $dateToString as the value of the _id field. Then it works, but only then. It is these kinds of inconsistencies that frustrate me with Mongo.