# Group by day/month/week basis on the date range

Tags: mongodb, date, group-by, aggregation-framework, mongodb-aggregation

This is in reference to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38897478/group-by-day-month-and-take-average-of-rating-on-that-day-month-in-mongo/38900028?noredirect=1#comment65783720_38900028).

This is my data set:

```
[
  {
    "rating": 4,
    "ceatedAt": ISODate("2016-08-08T15:32:41.262+0000")
  },
  {
    "rating": 3,
    "createdAt": ISODate("2016-08-08T15:32:41.262+0000")
  },
  {
    "rating": 3,
    "ceatedAt": ISODate("2016-07-01T15:32:41.262+0000")
  },
  {
    "rating": 5,
    "createdAt": ISODate("2016-07-01T15:32:41.262+0000")
  }
]
```

I want to be able to filter basis on week or month basis on the date range.

How would I do that in mongo?

This was the answer given for grouping by days.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { 
        "$project": {
            "formattedDate": { 
                "$dateToString": { "format": "%Y-%m-%d", "date": "$ceatedAt" } 
            },
            "createdAtMonth": { "$month": "$ceatedAt" },
            "rating": 1
        }
    },
    {
         "$group": {
             "_id": "$formattedDate",
             "average": { "$avg": "$rating" },
             "month": { "$first": "$createdAtMonth" },
         }
    }
])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For grouping on weekly basis, run the following pipeline which mainly uses the [Date Aggregation Operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#date-operators) to extract the date parts:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { 
        "$project": {
            "createdAtWeek": { "$week": "$createdAt" },
            "createdAtMonth": { "$month": "$createdAt" },
            "rating": 1
        }
    },
    {
         "$group": {
             "_id": "$createdAtWeek",
             "average": { "$avg": "$rating" },
             "month": { "$first": "$createdAtMonth" }
         }
    }
])
```

and for monthly aggregates, interchange the **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** key to use the created month field:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { 
        "$project": {
            "createdAtWeek": { "$week": "$createdAt" },
            "createdAtMonth": { "$month": "$createdAt" },
            "rating": 1
        }
    },
    {
         "$group": {
             "_id": "$createdAtMonth",
             "average": { "$avg": "$rating" },
             "week": { "$first": "$createdAtWeek" }
         }
    }
])
```