# convert iso date to timestamp in mongo query

Tags: mongodb, date, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

here is the query

```
[
    { 
        "$project": {
            "formattedDate": { 
                "$dateToString": { "format": "%Y-%m-%d", "date": "$ceatedAt" } 
            },
            "createdAtMonth": { "$month": "$ceatedAt" },
            "rating": 1
        }
    },
    {
         "$group": {
             "_id": "$formattedDate",
             "average": { "$avg": "$rating" },
             "month": { "$first": "$createdAtMonth" },
         }
    }
]
```

I need the date in timestamp. How to do that?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use [**`$subtract`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract/) *arithmetic aggregation operator* with your Date as *minuend* and `new Date("1970-01-01")` as *subtrahend*.

```
db.collection.aggregate(
  {
    $project: { "timestamp": { $subtract: [ "$createdAt", new Date("1970-01-01") ] } } 
  }
);
```

For document

```
{ "_id": 1, "createdAt": ISODate("2016-09-01T14:35:14.952Z") }
```

the result is

```
{ "_id": 1, "timestamp": NumberLong("1472740514952") }
```

If you want to group both by timestamp and (year, month, date) you can divide timestamp by the amount of milliseconds in a day, so that it will be unique for each day (and not for each millisecond)

```
db.collection.aggregate(
  {
    $project: 
      {
        "timestampByDay":
          {
            $floor: 
              {
                $divide: 
                  [ 
                    { $subtract: [ "$createdAt", new Date("1970-01-01") ] }, 
                    24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 
                  ] 
              }
          },
        "date": "$createdAt"
      }
  },
  {
    $group:
      {
        "_id": "$timestampByDay",
        "date": { $first: "$date" }
      }
  }
);
```

Comment: But, will I get the grouped data for that date?

Comment: No if you want to group by the value of (year, month, day). Could you provide some documents and expected result in your question?

Comment: Yes, basis on the input request I will group by month, week, day. 
Here is the answer I got for month and week - it works: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39269760/group-by-day-month-week-basis-on-the-date-range/
Now, when I group by day, I need to show the timestamp and not date string.

Comment: In group, will I have to add _id: timestampByDay ?

Comment: Yes, than it will be grouped with (year, month, date) being unique. But note that in the result output you will not get real timestamp of your Date as `_id`, but you will get timestamp divided by `24 * 60 * 60 * 1000`.

Comment: I am getting this in timestampByDay - 17023.4279265625. What does this imply? And I don't get grouped data. Could you kindly also add how to get grouped data. It can be just for day.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I forgot to add [**`$floor`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/floor/) operator. Updated the answer. Now it should be 17023, and in your case it implies unique day identificator, the day number after `1970-01-01`.

Comment: And if I have to convert 17023 back to normal date on front-end, will it be possible?

Comment: It will be much easier not to convert it from 17023, but to simply add it to your `$project` stage and then use `$first` operator as you did for the month.

Comment: Can you please provide that in answer?

Comment: I updated the answer. If you need another result, it would be much easier if you **update your question** with expected one.

Answer (score 29):

Mongodb **4.0** has introduced [**`$toLong`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toLong/) aggregation which convert date to timestamp

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "createdAt": {
      "$toLong": "$createdAt"
    }
  }}
])
```

You can try it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/q05C_IysV24)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to update timestamp. with the current date and time use the below query.

```
db.getCollection('movie').update(
{"applicationId":"2b5958d9629026491c30b42f2d5256fa8","type":"shortcut"},
{$set : {userName:"vipin+testkm23052020@applozic.com",created_at: NumberLong(new Date()),"updated_at":NumberLong(new Date()),"docIndex":UUID()}}, {multi:true, upsert: false}
)
```