# Mongo: convert all document from ISODate to timeStamp

Tags: mongodb

I am new guy in mongodb, please help me about the question:
I have a collection with many document:

```
PRIMARY> db.submoney.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("574d0404880b0e62923a52e1"), "dateLastRenewal" : ISODate("2016-02-18T07:02:04Z")}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("574d0404880b0e629233a521"), "dateLastRenewal" : ISODate("2016-03-18T07:02:04Z")}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("574d0404880b0e62923a555"), "dateLastRenewal" : ISODate("2016-04-18T07:02:04Z")}
```

How could i change all my document dateLastRenewal (ISODATE to timestamp)?

Many Thanks,

Comment: `isoDate.getTime()` to get the epoch

Comment: possible duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39274311/convert-iso-date-to-timestamp-in-mongo-query

Comment: why do you want to?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert iso date to timestamp in mongo query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39274311/convert-iso-date-to-timestamp-in-mongo-query)