# Mongo. How I can update createdAt by timestamp of _id

Tags: mongodb

My current data does not included `createdAt` yet. Now I want to write a script to update all exist records.

I tried with:

```
db.getCollection('storageunits').aggregate([
    {
        "$addFields": {
            "createdAt": "$_id.getTimestamp()"
         }
    }
])
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: try:

   ObjectId("507c7f79bcf86cd7994f6c0e").getTimestamp()

Comment: I don’t want a specify id. $_id is id of itself, that will use $_id of itself to update itself createdAt. $_id is a dynamic value

Comment: I also try: “$_id”.getTimestamp() or ObjectId(“_id”).getTimestamp(). It didn’t work too

Comment: which mongo verison are you using?

Comment: My mongo version is 4.0.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Calculate `timestamp` from `_id`

#### Option 1

You can use [$toLong](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toLong/#behavior) with combination of [$toDate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/#behavior) or [$convert](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/convert/#exp._S_convert) operators for `_id` field  (>= `v4.0`):

```
db.getCollection('storageunits').aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      "createdAt": {
        $toLong: {
          $toDate: "$_id"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2_R91LiEg7i) | [with $convert](https://mongoplayground.net/p/WLHbMcLa_zb)

#### Option 2

You can use [$toDate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/#behavior) or [$convert](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/convert/#exp._S_convert) operators for `_id` field and subtract `01/01/1970` (>= `v4.0`):

```
db.getCollection('storageunits').aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      "createdAt": {
        $subtract: [
          {
            $toDate: "$_id"
          },
          new Date("1970-01-01")
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hiFkPMqokLV) | [Convert date to timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39274311/convert-iso-date-to-timestamp-in-mongo-query)

### Update collection with `createdAt`

#### Option 1

Add extra operator to your aggregation (>= v4.0).
 **This will override entire collection with documents from aggregation result**

```
{$out: "storageunits"}
```

#### Option 2

Since MongoDB `v4.2`, we can [perform aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#update-with-aggregation-pipeline) inside update method

```
db.getCollection('storageunits').update({},
  [
    { "$set": { "createdAt": { $toLong: { $toDate: "$_id" }}}}
  ],
  { "multi" : true}
)
```

Comment: Thanks, it's worked. But typeof createdAt is Int64. How I can store createdAt with DateTime type. It should be human datetime format

Comment: Successfully.
I tried: 
```db.getCollection('storageunits').aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      "createdAt": {
        $toDate: "$_id"
      }
    }
  }
])``` and it works very well. Many thanks to you

Comment: @VũAnhDũng My first answer was `$toDate`, but then I've changed strictly to timestamp